# Filling a data-frame after multiple loops in R

Tags: r, loops, dataframe, for-loop, fill

I am doing multiple loops and I want to create a dataframe with the different results.

A MWE is as follows:

```
# define cases 
debt   <-c(0,0.05) 
thetas <- c(1, 1.5) 
rhos   <- c(0, 0.99, 2) # 0:C-D case, 1 = linear (no effect on prices)%
```

Then want to loop over the above vectors

```
for (theta in thetas){
  for (rho in rhos){
    for (b in debt) {
      sols <-nleqslv(0.05, k_ss) # k_ss is defined in the end
      kss  <-round(sols$x,5)
    }
  }
}
```

I want in each iteration store the `kss`values and create a dataframe that should essentially summarize all possible `(i.e. length(theta)*length(rho)*length(debt) = 12 in this example)` combinations in one simple to understand dataframe.

My expected result should look as follows:

```
thetas <- c(1, 1.5) 
rhos   <- c(0,0.99, 2) # 0:C-D case, 1 = linear (no effect on prices)%
debts   <-c(0,0.05) 

n = length(debt)*length(thetas)*length(rhos)

theta<-c(rep(1,6),rep(1.5,6))
rho  <-c(rep(0,2),rep(0.99,2), rep(2,2), rep(0,2),rep(0.99,2), rep(2,2))
debt <-rep(c(0,0.05),6)
kss  <-rnorm(12,0,1)  # suppose these are my true ('expected' kss valuesthat i get for the iterations

df   <- data.frame(theta,rho,debt,kss)

 df
   theta  rho debt     kss
1    1.0 0.00 0.00  1.1090
2    1.0 0.00 0.05  1.8436
3    1.0 0.99 0.00  0.7718
4    1.0 0.99 0.05  0.5628
5    1.0 2.00 0.00 -1.1774
6    1.0 2.00 0.05  2.1973
7    1.5 0.00 0.00  0.8531
8    1.5 0.00 0.05 -0.1252
9    1.5 0.99 0.00  0.4784
10   1.5 0.99 0.05  1.8334
11   1.5 2.00 0.00  0.3693
12   1.5 2.00 0.05  1.0470
```

Just for the record **here is how my kss is generated**:

```
# compute steady state 



k_ss<-function(k){
  # this function is defined for given values in b, theta, rho 
  # all other variables not defined here are some scalars not defined here 
  # for simplicity 

  if (rho == 0){
    R <- A*alpha*k^(alpha-1)      
    w <- A*(1-alpha)*k^(alpha)    

  } else{
    y  <-A*(alpha*k^rho + (1-alpha))^(1/rho)
    R  <- A*alpha*(y/A*k)^(1-rho)           
    w  <- A*(1-alpha)*(y/A)^(1-rho)  

   }

  kt  <-nn*(dt/beta*nn)^(1/theta)
  sd  <-((beta*R)^(1/theta))*(1+kt)/(R+(beta*R)^(1/theta)*(1+kt))
  mpb <-(1/nn)*(kt/(1+kt))
  ego <-sd/(1-sd*mpb*R)

  kss <-(nn)*(k+b) - (ego*(w-(R-nn)*b))

  return(kss)

}
```

And then:

```
sols <-nleqslv(0.05, k_ss)
      kss  <-round(sols$x,5)
```

Comment: How do you calculate `kss` ? Is it just sum of every `debt + thetas + rhos` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One possible solution with `pmap` from `purrr` and `mutate` from `dplyr` is the following. Here you can replace `my_function` with whatever you are trying to accomplish. Note that `pmap_dbl` expects to return a double, but you could also use `pmap` which then returns a list.

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)

theta <- c(1, 1.5)
rho  <- c(0, 0.99, 2)
debt <- c(0, 0.05)

my.df <- expand.grid(theta = theta, rho = rho, debt = debt)

my_function <- function(theta, rho, debt) {
  kss  <- theta + rho + debt
}

my.df %>% 
  mutate(kss = pmap_dbl(list(theta = theta, rho = rho, debt = debt), my_function)) %>% 
  arrange(theta, rho, debt)


#    theta  rho debt  kss
# 1    1.0 0.00 0.00 1.00
# 2    1.0 0.00 0.05 1.05
# 3    1.0 0.99 0.00 1.99
# 4    1.0 0.99 0.05 2.04
# 5    1.0 2.00 0.00 3.00
# 6    1.0 2.00 0.05 3.05
# 7    1.5 0.00 0.00 1.50
# 8    1.5 0.00 0.05 1.55
# 9    1.5 0.99 0.00 2.49
# 10   1.5 0.99 0.05 2.54
# 11   1.5 2.00 0.00 3.50
# 12   1.5 2.00 0.05 3.55
```

`pmap` replaces the loops you specified. It takes a function and applies it to each row of the data.frame `my.df` and uses the arguments that are specified in the list as arguments for the function.

With `arrange`, you can order it such that you have the original order.

Comment: should I put this (the mutate command) inside the main loops?

Comment: For some reason does not work. I have updated my example, so maybe now could things be improved if you can please have a look again.

Comment: Did you replace the `kss  <- theta + rho + debt` by `sols <-nleqslv(0.05, k_ss)` and `kss  <-round(sols$x,5)`? Your example is not reproducible. We are missing a lot of variables like A, alpha, y. Also I think you redefine `k_ss` for each new theta and rho, so you need to put the definition of `k_ss` also in the my_function call.

Comment: Will try again, values that I have not defined are just scalars defined elsewhere in my code. So, is not the most important issue.

Comment: It is an issue when we want to help you but have to first figure out how to run your code, or it is not possible at all.

Comment: It now worked after you suggested (i.e. put the function inside to the my_function) but, the order of the kss values do not represent the true combination of the values I was looping over.

Comment: I have updated my question, just in case you see something more useful.

Answer (score 1):

If `kss` is just the sum of `debt`, `rho` and `theta`, it can be done quite easily:

```r
thetas <- c(1, 1.5) 
rhos   <- c(0, 0.99, 2)
debts   <-c(0, 0.05)

df <- expand.grid(theta = thetas, rho = rhos, debt =debts)

non_linear_equation_solver <- function(theta, rho, debt) {
  kss <- (theta + rho + debt) # for example
  return(kss)
}

df$kss <- apply(df, 1, function(x) non_linear_equation_solver(x[1], x[2], x[3]))

df
#>    theta  rho debt  kss
#> 1    1.0 0.00 0.00 1.00
#> 2    1.5 0.00 0.00 1.50
#> 3    1.0 0.99 0.00 1.99
#> 4    1.5 0.99 0.00 2.49
#> 5    1.0 2.00 0.00 3.00
#> 6    1.5 2.00 0.00 3.50
#> 7    1.0 0.00 0.05 1.05
#> 8    1.5 0.00 0.05 1.55
#> 9    1.0 0.99 0.05 2.04
#> 10   1.5 0.99 0.05 2.54
#> 11   1.0 2.00 0.05 3.05
#> 12   1.5 2.00 0.05 3.55
```

<sup>Created on 2019-03-17 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.1)</sup>

Comment: Sorry, in my original case Kss is not the sum of the rows. I put it here as a sum of the rows mostly for convenience. In my real case, Kss is a solution to a non linear equation.

Comment: In that case, you can use `df$kss<-apply(df,1,f)`, where `f` is your non-linear function taking a vector of length 3 as argument.

Comment: it misses the step where f is solved, I don't see it. the 'rhos' , 'thetas' are parameters of the function, kss is the root of this function for a given combination of parameter values. Hence, the loop -- because I am looking at values for kss for a different combination of these parameters.

Comment: The step `df <- expand.grid(theta = thetas, rho = rhos, debt =debts)` creates all possible combinations. So, if you have a function `f` to solve the equation given a vector (for example `c(1.0, 0.00, 0.00)`), this should work.

Comment: Still, kss is the root of a non-linear function (polynomianl) -- so I use a non-linear solver which calls 'f' . I think this is what is missing.

Comment: Without further information, it's impossible to guess what you're trying to do. I think you should be able to modify for your own problem from here.

Comment: I think the essence of what I want to achieve is well explained. Because my problem is not how 'kss' is generated,  but on how to store the results into a dataframe as explained.

Answer (score 0):

I found another very intuitive solution:

first as suggested by @kath define a general function which takes as inputs the parameters over which one wants to loop over:

```
my_function <- function(theta, rho, debt) {
  kss <- (theta + rho + debt) 
}
```

Then the asked dataframe can be constructed as follows:

```
output<-list() # create an empty list 
i     <-0   # counter 

for (theta in thetas){
  for (rho in rhos){
    for (b in debt) {
      i=i+1
      kss<-my_function(theta,rho,b)
      output[[i]]<-data.frame(Theta = theta, Rho = rho, Debt = b, K = kss)
    }
  }
}
```

Then bind the dataframes from the list:

```
df<-do.call(rbind,output)

And here is the result: 

Theta  Rho Debt    K
1    1.0 0.00 0.00 1.00
2    1.0 0.00 0.05 1.05
3    1.0 0.99 0.00 1.99
4    1.0 0.99 0.05 2.04
5    1.0 2.00 0.00 3.00
6    1.0 2.00 0.05 3.05
7    1.5 0.00 0.00 1.50
8    1.5 0.00 0.05 1.55
9    1.5 0.99 0.00 2.49
10   1.5 0.99 0.05 2.54
11   1.5 2.00 0.00 3.50
12   1.5 2.00 0.05 3.55
>
```